# Scale mesh1, mesh2 automatically change it's position?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Basicially I like to connect the right side of mesh 1 to the left side of mesh 2.

Currently, If I scale mesh1 I have to reposition mesh2 in order to have the same distance as before.

So let's scale **mesh 1** to  z: 2

```
var tween = new TWEEN.Tween(mesh1.scale).to({ z: 2 }, 1000).start();
tween.easing(TWEEN.Easing.Elastic.InOut);
```

In order to have the same distance to mesh 1 as before I have to reposition **mesh 2** to z:1.5

```
var tween = new TWEEN.Tween(mesh2.position).to({ z: 1.5 }, 1000).start();
tween.easing(TWEEN.Easing.Elastic.InOut);
```

Are there any options in connecting the colored mesh faces. So If I scale mesh 1, mesh 2 automatically change it's position?

[image]

...

```
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );


var mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, 
new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0x222222}));
mesh1 .position.set( 0, 0, 0 );
mesh1 .scale.set( 1, 1, 1 );
scene.add( mesh1 );

var mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, 
new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0x222222}));
mesh2 .position.set( 0, 0, 1 );
mesh2 .scale.set( 1, 1, 1 );
scene.add( mesh2 );
```

Comment: connect mesh face how?

Comment: You could add mesh2 to mesh1 `mesh1.add(mesh2)`. However, every transformation (translation, rotation, scaling) of mesh1 will be inherited to mesh2. But I guess, that's not what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is a geometric problem.**

I haven't worked with three.js before, but I believe I have a geometric solution.

Consider a third imaginary mesh, `mesh3`, such that it is a combination of `mesh1` and `mesh2`.

That is:

```
mesh1: position(0, 0, 0), scale(1, 1, 1);
mesh2: position(0, 0, 1), scale(1, 1, 1);
mesh3: position(0, 0, 0), scale(1, 1, 2); // Loosely, mesh3 = mesh1 + mesh2
```

Now to scale the structure by a scalar `k`, I propose two approaches:

**Approach 1:**

1. Scale `mesh1` and `mesh3` each by `k`.
2. Compute the difference between `mesh3` and `mesh1`, `meshDiff`.
3. Set `mesh2` = `meshDiff`.

**Approach 2:**

1. Scale `mesh3` by `k`.
2. Compute two halves of `mesh3`, `mesh31` and `mesh32`, such that they are oriented along `mesh1` and `mesh2` respectively.
3. Set `mesh1` = `mesh31` and `mesh2` = `mesh32`.

The approaches are very similar. Keep three.js's API in mind to choose the best approach.

**Note:** You needn't ever render `mesh3`. It only exists as a computational aid.

**Generality:**

The idea presented above can be used in other situations as well, wherein geometries sharing a common feature need to be scaled.

Hope this helps.

**PS:** I realize that this answer is a little abstract. Nonetheless, I hope it helps.